# App crashing when navigating to a new screen (jetpack compose)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to create a timer app which will ask for details in the start screen and implement and display the timer in another screen. However when trying to navigate from the start screen to the timer screen the app just crashes. When I looked at the logcat I got a null pointer exception but I'm not sure why:

java.lang.NullPointerException                                                                                                  at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1652)                                                                                                    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1984)                                                                                                 at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate$default(NavController.kt:1979)

Any help would be appreciated.

**Setting up the nav host and nav controller**

```
package com.example.myapplication.ui

import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController

enum class TimerRoutes() {
    StartScreen,
    TimerScreen
}

@Composable
fun TimerApp() {
    val navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = TimerRoutes.StartScreen.name) {

        composable(route = TimerRoutes.StartScreen.name) {
            TimerStartScreen(navController)
        }

        composable(route = TimerRoutes.TimerScreen.name) {
            TimerScreen()
        }

    }
}
```

**TimerStartScreen**

```
package com.example.myapplication.ui
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TextField
import androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBar
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.collectAsState
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.ImeAction
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController


@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun TimerStartScreen(navController: NavHostController) {
    val viewModel: TimerViewModel = viewModel()
    val timerUiState = viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter) {
        Column() {
            TopAppBar(title = {Text(text = "Start Screen", textAlign = TextAlign.Center)})
            TextField(
                value = timerUiState.value.name,
                onValueChange = { viewModel.updateNameText(it) },
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(top = 16.dp, start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp),
                label = { Text(text = "Enter Timer Name") }
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

            TextField(
                value = timerUiState.value.date,
                onValueChange = {viewModel.updateCurrentDateNumber(it)},
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp),
                label = { Text(text = "Enter Date of Event (dd/MM/yyyy)")},
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
            Button(
                onClick = {navController.navigate(TimerRoutes.TimerScreen.name)},
                content = { Text(text = "Create!")},
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 135.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**TimerScreen**

```
package com.example.myapplication.ui

import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.collectAsState
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel

@Composable
fun TimerScreen() {
    val viewModel: TimerViewModel = viewModel()
    val timerUiState = viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()

    viewModel.findNumberOfDaysAndHoursLeft(timerUiState.value.date)

    Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter) {
        Column() {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))

            Row(){
                Text(text = "Days: ${timerUiState.value.diffInDays.toString()}", modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 110.dp))
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(15.dp))
                Text(text = "Hours: ${timerUiState.value.diffInHours.toString()}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong. I needed to make sure that I was initialising the nav controller and viewModel only once and then passing them into each composable if required. What I was initially doing was I was making making initialising those variable in each composable.